# What counts as an illegal hierarchical reference for a virtual interface?

Tags: system-verilog

The *IEEE 1800-2017* LRM states in section **25.9 Virtual interfaces** that:

> Although an interface may contain hierarchical references to objects outside its body or ports that reference
>   other interfaces, it shall be illegal to use an interface containing those references in the declaration of a
>   virtual interface.

Is the following an example of such a disallowed hierarchical reference?

```
interface some_other_intf();
  bit some_signal;
endinterface


interface some_intf();

  some_other_intf intf();

  task foo();
    intf.some_signal <= 0;
  endtask

endinterface


virtual some_intf some_vif;
```

I have a tool that complains about the line containing `intf.some_signal <= 0`. While `intf.some_signal` is a hierarchical reference, it's a relative reference, so I don't see why this would be disallowed.

`intf` is part of the interface body. I'm not sure how to interpret the *ports that reference other interfaces* part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of a port that references another interface

```
interface some_other_intf();
  bit some_signal;
  parameter T = int;
endinterface

interface some_intf(some_other_interface intf);    
  task foo();
    intf.some_signal <= 0;
  endtask
typefef intf.T myT;
myT another_signal;
endinterface
virtual some_intf some_vif;
```

The problem comes in with a reference to `some_vif.another_signal` Its type could change depending on what parametrization of T got connected to `intf`.

For most use cases, this is not a problem, but the SystemVerilog committee never spent the time on clarifying specific cases that could be allowed; the just made a wide sweeping prohibition.

Comment: So "port that references another interface" can be read as "port of interface type".

Comment: Is the example I showed a disallowed hierarchical reference, though?

Comment: Yes, containing a port of an interface type is another way to say it. "Interfaces" and "virtual interfaces" are some of the most poorly documented constructs in the LRM. Your example is considered a hierarchical reference, but I think the restriction is more concerned with references that are not on a direct downward path.

Comment: Is this suggestion from Brad problematic then? I get this same issue when trying to create a virtual interface of one of the slices. https://bradpierce.wordpress.com/2014/07/06/how-to-slice-a-systemverilog-interface/