# Virtual interface element uses an interface with interface ports [warning from QuestaSIM vlog/vsim]

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

What is the meaning of the following warning issued by QuestaSIM's vsim? What is the simulator worried about here? I haven't been able to produce an actual simulation error from this yet.

**My guess:** it has something to do with interface instances vs. virtual interface instances, but my understanding is minimal.

> ** Warning: (vsim-8887) tests/base_test.svh(28): Virtual interface element 'this.apb_driver_bfm_vi.clk' uses an interface with interface ports.

`apb_driver_bfm_vi` is a virtual interface handle to the following interface:

```
interface apb_driver_bfm(
    input logic clk,
    input logic nrst,
    apb_if.apb_s apb_if_i // apb_if is itself an interface, apb_s is a modport.
);

endinterface : apb_driver_bfm
```

The virtual interface is used as follows: `@(posegde apb_driver_bfm_vi.clk);` in the run_phase of my testbench. This seems to work fine, despite the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From section *25.9 Virtual interfaces* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)

> Although an interface may contain hierarchical references to objects outside its body or ports that reference other interfaces, it shall be illegal to use an interface containing those references in the declaration of a virtual interface.

this a problem when the interface port gets connected to a parameterized interface and different instances of the virtual interface have different parameterizations. This is not a problem when the interfaces have the same parameters, but the LRM is overly pessimistic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627223/what-counts-as-an-illegal-hierarchical-reference-for-a-virtual-interface is relevant (added for reference).

Comment: As a follow up, how would pass a handle to a parametrized interface from the HDL domain to the HVL domain using a BFM interface? If I understood correctly, storing a virtual interface handle to the BFM in the UVM resource database would cause issues.